The set of limit points of a set is closed, proof verification
Is this proof for the set of limit points of a set being closed valid?
Let $A$ denote the set of limit points of $B$. For all $x \in A$, there exists a sequence $(b_{x_n})$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, b_{x_n} \in B$. For any sequence $(a_k)$ such that $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, a_k \in A, a_k \rightarrow$ some $a$. Let $b_{k_n}$ denote a sequence converging to the kth term of $a_k$. As $b_{k_n} \rightarrow a_k$, $\forall \epsilon/2>0, \exists N_1$ such that $\forall n>N_1, |b_{k_n}-a_k|<\epsilon/2$. Similarly for $a_k \rightarrow a$, $\forall \epsilon/2, \exists N_2$ such that $\forall k>N_2, |a_k-a|<\epsilon/2$. Let $N=max\{N_1, N_2\}$. Thus it follows that $\forall k>N, |b_{k_k}-a_k|+|a_k-a|<\epsilon$, and by the triangle inequality, $|b_{k_k}-a|<\epsilon$, so for all such sequences in the set of limit points must have their limit in the set of limit points. By the definition of a closed set (it must contain all of its limit points), the set of limit points is therefore closed.
I think the logic checks out, but I've got a really weird feeling around $|b_{k_k}-a_k|<\epsilon/2$ being false. Pretty sure I should trust my spidey-senses in it being wrong, but I want to make sure. Thanks!

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Edited! Thanks.

What is “the sequence converging to the $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ term of $a_k$”?

For all elements in $a_k$, there is a sequence in B which converges to $a_k$. This is because each element of A is a limit point of B, and each element in $a_k$ is in A.

Indeed. But, in general, there are infinitely many such sequences, and therefore it makes no sense to talk about the sequence.

Ah, okay. Let's instead say "a" sequence then.

Your tag is general topology, but this is not a true fact of general topology, see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2116855/set-of-limit-points-is-closed-in-a-general-topological-space

If the scope is "general topology", then the sequential argument never works and you may as well scratch everything that relies on that. By "limit point", do you mean an adherent point, i.e. a point $x$ such that every neighbourhood of $x$ contains a point of $B$, or do you mean a cluster point, i.e. a point $x$ such that every neighbourhood of $x$ contains a point of $B\setminus{x}$ ?

Your proof is not correct. The problem lies at the point at which you say$$\exists N_1\text{ such that }\forall n>N_1,\ |b_{k_n}-a_k|<\frac\varepsilon2.$$In fact, that number $N_1$ depends upon $k$, and so it should be$$\exists N_1(k)\text{ such that }\forall n>N_1(k),\ |b_{k_n}-a_k|<\frac\varepsilon2.$$But then you cannot define $N$ as $\max\{N_1,N_2\}$.

Ah, I suspected it was something to do with the $N_1$. Many thanks!
